# Espace HTML tags in a razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, escaping

I am trying to display a data containing arrow characters in my razor view.
This is the data I want to be displayed:

```
<mydata>data.
```

The problem is that when this data is displayed, it's rendered like this:

```
data.
```

And when I inspect the dom with google inspector, the DOM appears like this:

```
<mydata>data.</mydata>
```

How can I tell in my razor view, to no transform my content to be displayed into an html tag and display it as it is? I have try the `HtmlUtility.Encode` without success.

Comment: It's not Razor that is closing your `<mydata>` element. If you'll look at the raw response from the server (ctrl +U in Chrome) you'll notice that it's returned *as is*. It's your Browser that parses it into a DOM tree, and automatically closes it.

Comment: So you're telling me that there is no solution ?

Comment: I'm telling you that you're emitting an invalid HTML and your Browser is forced to close it somehow to make sense of your DOM. That mysterious `<mydata>` tag *has* to be closed somehow. I would say you better close it yourself in your own code

Comment: It's not a tag. It's a data, that for a functional reason, must be displayed like that (ie <mydata>).

Comment: Can it be self-enclosing (`<mydata />`)? You'll have to add some more context to your question so we can understand what and why exactly is it there?

Answer (score 0):

How are you emitting the value from Razor? Have you tried using @Html.Raw(Your value) , this way, it will render the value as you applied it in the code. the [@Html.Raw() extension returns markup that is not HTMLEncoded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Convert "<" to HTML Entity then it will work

```
EG:- &lt;mydata&gt;data.
```

It will render as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
@Html.Raw("&lt;mydata&gt;data.");
```